# Creating a file transfer application using UDP in C

Tags: c, udp, client-server

I am trying to implement a server-client application in which the client sends the name of file to server. The server looks for the file and if the file exist it sends the file to the client back and this goes on . Here is the code i have written but the problem is that the server does not send the content of file back to client  I had the same problem earlier ,then i re-wrote the code .

Here is the code :-

Server Side

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buff[20];
    char content[200];
    int sd, connfd, len, bytes_read;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (sd == -1) {
        puts("socket not created in server");
        return 1;
    } else {
        puts("socket created in server");
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(7802);

    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        puts("Not binded");
        return 1;
    } else {
        puts("Binded");
    }

    len = sizeof(cliaddr);

    recvfrom(sd, buff, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);

    printf("%s\n", buff);

    FILE *fp = fopen(buff, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist \n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        bytes_read = read(fp, content, sizeof(content));
        if (bytes_read == 0)
            break;
        sendto(sd, content, sizeof(content), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, len);
        bzero(content, 200);
    }
    strcpy(content, "end");
    sendto(sd, content, sizeof(content), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, len);

    return 0;
}
```

Client side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    char buff[20], output[20];
    char file_buffer[200];
    int sockfd, connfd, len;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (sockfd == -1) {
        puts("socket not created in client");
        return 1;
    } else {
        puts("socket created in  client");
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // ANY address or use specific address
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(7802);  // Port address

    puts("Type your UDP client message");
    scanf("%s", buff);
    puts("enter the name of new file to be saved");
    scanf("%s", output);

    // send msg to server
    sendto(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff) + 1, 0,
           (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    count++;
    printf("%d\n", count);

    FILE *fp = fopen(output, "a");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        puts("error in file handling");
        return 1;
    }
    recvfrom(sockfd, file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer), 0, NULL, NULL);
    while (1) {
        if (strcmp(file_buffer, "end") == 0)
            break;
        printf("%s", file_buffer);
        write(fp, file_buffer, strlen(file_buffer));
        bzero(file_buffer, 200);
        recvfrom(sockfd, file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer), 0, NULL, NULL);
    }

    puts("completed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what exactly is happening?

Comment: This is how the code is supposed to work 
1. Client sends a name of file (buff)
2. The server looks the for the file ,if the file exists it opens it read it and send the contents to the client.
3.client asks for the name of file in which the output file is to be stored and writes the content from the server to the file.

But after compiling the code and running an output file gets created but the content from server oes not get written into it .

Comment: Have you fixed the client side? You also use the `fopen()` and `write()` instead of `frwite()`.

Comment: What are you suggesting using fopen amd wite in client ? Already done that!

Comment: No, `fwrite()` instead of `write()`

Comment: here is what i have done in client 
printf("%s",file_buffer);
       ret=fwrite(file_buffer,1,sizeof(file_buffer),fp);

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use the `fread()` function instead of `read()` on server side.

Functions `fopen()` and `read()` are parts of different interfaces:

> Family read() -> open, close, read, write, ioctl (system calls)
>
> Family fread() -> fopen, fclose, fread, fwrite, fcntl (standard library)

I can suppose that file descriptor given by `fopen()` is not exactly the same as `read()` expects.

The same on client side. You use the `fopen()` to open file and `write()` to write. Please use the `fwrite()`

Comment: Which, being translated, means: in the server code, you open the file with `fopen()` but you try to read the file using `read()` passing the file pointer as the file descriptor, which is not going to work.  (A) pay attention to your compiler warnings — if you aren't getting any, turn the warnings on or get a better compiler.  (B) use `fread()` for file streams opened with `fopen(); use `read()` for file descriptors created with `open()`, `socket()`, etc.

Comment: here is the snippet of code in server

     while(1)
        {
          end=fread(content,strlen(content)+1,1,fp);
          if(end==0)
     break;
          }

Comment: @UdayMittal: Your `fread` call seems wrong. why are you using `strlen()` there?

Comment: i have modified it to sizeof(content) that's a typo~